# Ajax ComboBox rendering ListItems correctly but not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here ddlSchool is the ajax Combo box

```
<code>
ddlSchool.DataSource = dt;
                             ddlSchool.DataTextField = "SchoolName";
                             ddlSchool.DataValueField = "Id";
                             ddlSchool.DataBind();
                             ddlSchool.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(" --Select-- ", "0"));
                             ddlSchool.SelectedValue = "0";
</code>
```

when I inspect it renders the value but not displaying due to the following ,

```
<code>
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSchool_ddlSchool_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 1000; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 416px; position: absolute; height: 425px; left: 293px; top: 1458px; display: none;"></ul>
</code>
```

Please help me to get the ListItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the listbox is not displaying at the exact place. This is because of bootstrap while splitting the columns into 3. The space is not enough to display line items.So it is displaying at some other place.Need to change the bootstrap column settings to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing:

```
style="visibility: hidden;display: none;
```

from the style settings

Also, as it is position absolute, it may be displaying somewhere else on the page eg not where you expect to see it

Comment: I tried it is appearing as default becoz the itemlist i have binded from codebehind. So it displays as unordered list of items.

Comment: <ul> is appeared only during inspect.I never declared anything in the source file

Comment: Try removing it using developer tools in Chrome once it is built and displaying in your browser, then see if the items appear as intended

Comment: Yes I tried all these options. and also style="visibility:visible"; also I tried but no use

Comment: If you remove the visibility setting and also the display:none in chrome developer tools does it display your item? If so, you need to find why it is adding this styling to your item. Try searching your whole project for something unique within the style block. IF you are using a plugin look into the plugin to see if you can see why it is doing this